# Problems with multiple update panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a page that contains multiple update panels.
I usually set `updatemode='conditional'`, but if I update the data in one of the update panels I have to update all of the other update panels otherwise an error occurs in firebug's console window and the page hangs, what should I do to solve this problem ?

[image]

For more details about this problem, the image above represent a simple page with two update panels. 
First gridview in `updatepanel1` with `updatemode='conditional'`.
 The rest of the page is in `updatepanel2` with `updatemode='conditional'`. 
The scenario is as follows: user select a day from the first gridview then I use 
`__doPostBack('btnRefresh', '');` in jquery to get the data to fill the second gridview. 
Note: the button with `id="btnRefresh"` exists in the second update panel. 
Please help me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Appointments.aspx.cs" Inherits="Appointments" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`enter code here`
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
            <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/FQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="style/style-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="style/ModalStyle-mini.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var cells;
                var isAdd = 1;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    DoWork();
                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(requestHandler);

                });
                function requestHandler(sender, args) {
                    DoWork();
                }
                function DoWork() {

                    $("#gvDays .row").click(function () {
                        $("#gvDays .row").removeClass("darkblue");
                        $(this).addClass("darkblue");
                        $("#txtPeriod").val("");
                        $("#txtDay_det_id").val("");
                        cells = $(this).find("td");
                        $("#txtDay_id").val($(cells[0]).text());
                        __doPostBack('btnRefresh', '');
                    });

                    $("#gvDayDet .row").click(function () {
                        $("#gvDayDet .row").removeClass("darkblue");
                        $(this).addClass("darkblue");
                        cells = $(this).find("td");
                        $("#txtDay_det_id").val($(cells[0]).text());
                        $("#txtTimeFrom").val($(cells[2]).text());
                        $("#txtTimeTo").val($(cells[3]).text());
                        $("#txtPeriod").val($(cells[4]).text());
                        __doPostBack('btnDaysDet', '');
                    });
                };
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

            <div id="catNewsTab">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDays" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="day_id" HeaderText="Day No." />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="day_name" HeaderText="Day Name" />
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gray" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="blue1 row" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="darkblue row" />
                </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDaysDet" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveDayDet" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveDayDet_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateDayDet" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdateDayDet_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteDayDet" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDeleteDayDet_Click" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay_id" runat="server" CssClass="hide" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" CssClass="hide" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />
     <asp:Button ID="btnDaysDet" runat="server" CssClass="hide" OnClick="btnDaysDet_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 326px;" class="scroll scrollsmall">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvDayDet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Results Found">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="day_det_id" HeaderText="day_det_id" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="day_id" HeaderText="day_id" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="time_from" HeaderText="time_from" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="time_to" HeaderText="time_to" />
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gray" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="blue1 row" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="darkblue row" />
                            <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="empty" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your aspx code, in particular the Update Panel area.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using jQuery for a PostBack instead of 'click' event in the code behind? If the 'Refresh' button is in the second UpdatePanel and it's only purpose is to update the GridView in the same UpdatePanel, then you don't need to specify an AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Hopefully this helps. If not, a sample code would be useful to provide a little more insight on the issue.

Comment: the reason that i don't have other way to do this

Comment: is there other way to do postback or what?

Comment: Try adding asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger under both update panel with ControlID set to btnRefresh

Comment: i tried what did you said but same problem even when add btnRefresh to updatepanel1
so what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but you can call `UpdatePanel1.Update()` from the code behind. In the `OnClick` event in the code behind (.vb file) you should be able to explicitly call update on each update panel:

```
UpdatePanel1.Update()
UpdatePanel2.Update()
```

...

Does this answer your question?

Comment: no i don't think so
i don't need to do that because when user select a row i give this selected row a style (color) to identify that this row is the selected
if i call UpdatePanel1.Update() it will disappears besides i think its make a heavy load on the page specially when the page contains more than update panel its huge data